# checking how long are comments in a file

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments

I just finished an assingment and according to the instructions I can't have a line of code or comment longer than 120 chars. is there a quick way to check that?
I'm using VSCODE on windows 10. I saw somewhere that I can make a verticle line in the editor to see if a row is too long but I can't find it now.

for example :
`// return stack->size since stack->size holds the number of values that can be stored inside the array at a given time.`

this comment is 119 chars so it is ok but anything bigger will cause me to lose points.

I know I can hold the last char in the sentence and see the 'col' number in VSCODE, I was hoping for something better.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"editor.rulers": [120]`

Look at the `Editor: Rulers` setting:

> Render vertical rulers after a certain number of monospace characters.
>   Use multiple values for multiple rulers. No rulers are drawn if array
>   is empty.

You can change its color or opacity like so  (in your settings.json):

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "editorRuler.foreground": "#ff0000ff",
}
```

That changes the color to red, the last two hex digits are opacity.  `ff` is 100% opaque.  So you could try more transparent with `#ff000080` for example.  Color and transparency are the only two modifications you can make to rulers.

Comment: Thank you! worked perfectly. is there a way to make the line transparent?

Comment: Transparent?  You wouldn't see it then.

Comment: I mean not solid.. I still want to see the line just don't want it to stand out

Comment: I edited the answer for info on changing the color and/or transparency of rulers.